# What is an identity element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

There exists an element $e\in G$, called the **identity element**, such that for any element $a\in G$

$e\circ a=a\circ e=a$

---

For each element $a\in G$, there exists an **inverse element** in $G$, denoted by $a^{-1}$, such that

$a\circ a^{-1}=a^{-1}\circ a=e$

---

These stated above, which I was wondering, what exactly does identity element mean?  And for identity and inverse element, what does the $e$ do and why does it equal what it equals?

I'm not sure what exactly $e$ does

Comment: It's the unique element of the group such that multiplying by it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does nothing! Literally. In addition it is 0 because $a+0=a$ so adding zero doesn't change it. In multiplication it is $1$ since $a\cdot1=a$

Comment: Oh!  So the identity element is basically 0 or 1 depending on addition or multiplication?  What would it mean if it was stated (the last part):         A subset H of G is a subgroup if and only if it satisfies
the following conditions:  "The identity of e of G is in H"?

Comment: Well, you're not always going to have 'addition' or 'multiplication' per se, but yeah, it's the thing that does nothing. Subgroups need to contain the identity element because they're supposed to look like groups themselves, which have an identity. There are other properties necessary for a subgroup, which I assume you just neglected to paste here.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I understand it a tad bit more.  As for the other properties, yes, there are two more, where "h_1, h_2 in H, then h_1h_2 in H."  and the last "if h in H, then h^-1 in H."